# Indicate my translation in in-text citation

Tags: translation, citation

I hope I'm not repeating this question although I could not find something relevant on this website.

I am looking for a way to indicate that a passage from a book is my translation. I'm using in-text citation and the text is part of a footnote. It goes like: "citation" (Author date, page). How could I indicate that the text in the citation is my translation?

I have found several solutions online, yet they either require a footnote (my quotation is part of a footnote already!) or they are too 'pompous' such as "Translated quotation that appeared in the paper:" which breaks the flow of my text. I would prefer something *discreet*; something like (Author date, page my translation) if possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what aspect of *English* this question is asking about. Are you looking for a *word* or *phrase* that indicates that a passage is your own translation? Or are you asking about stylistic conventions in typesetting that don't relate specifically to any particular language?

Comment: Can you say "translation by this author" or "this author's translation"?  Writers generally avoid referring to themselves, such as using the word 'my.'

Comment: Thank you Yosef. I think that "my emphasis" or "emphasis mine" are pretty common in academic writing.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm not sure that I understand your comment. I'm looking for a way to indicate that a citation is my translation without interrupting the flow of my text.

Comment: 'Translation from [language]'? you could have a citation/footnote at the end saying it is yours... See [this](http://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/ld/resources/writing/harvard/content/2.7-translated-text)

Comment: @JohnPap Stack Exchange is divided into communities focused on particular interests. *English Language and Usage* focuses on the interests of [linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question doesn't seem to be about linguistics or etymology, and I'm not sure what relevance *language* (in particular, English) has to your question.

Comment: I referenced some Turkish medical studies in my dissertation that had been translated and then put online, in the reference list my tutor told me to put square brackets around the title to indicate it had been translated. He told me that if I translated anything myself to write "translated by 'my name'" immediately after the closed bracket, but also warned me against it because my translation may be scrutinised.

Comment: @Lawrence Indeed, my question is not related to grammar, etymology etc. Perhaps you are right that it is irrelevant to the purposes of this forum. However, I am asking a specific question on citation in English language texts. Also, I'm not asking for someone to solve a unique problem that I have encountered. I'm asking for a proper way of citation in English. Isn't citation part of language?

Comment: @JohnPap While English works may contain citations, they may also contain charts and graphics, none of which is part of the language *per se*. [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) might be a more natural fit for questions about academic citation.

Comment: @Lawrence I don't think that English "contains" citations, rather they are part of language, as captions in charts and graphics are too. I understand that my question is not in the list of "welcomed" topics (although it is not to be found in the "non-welcomed" either). Moreover there are numerous questions about citations in this website. Are they all irrelevant?

Comment: I was referring to *works* (e.g. journal papers, theses, and other publications), not the *language* as the 'things' that may contain citations. As for whether the other questions about citations are on topic, they will need to considered on their individual merits. I'm just saying that *this* question seems off-topic at EL&U.

Comment: As for the difference of opinion as to what constitutes a question about *English*, please feel free to raise a question on [Meta.English.SE](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Lawrence I believe that there's no need for further argument here. I understand that you believe that some of the questions about citations are relevant to this site and others are not. If you believe that my question is off-topic (a matter on which I'm not convinced either that it is or is not) you may contact the administrators directly and I believe they can remove any of the questions about citations that do not meet with your guidelines on "merit". I don't feel any urge to raise a new question or further participate in such a discussion. Yet, you may do so if you like.

Comment: As it stands this question is out of scope for this site. You might check the guidelines for either [academia.se] or [writers.se] and see if it would be on topic there.

Comment: FYI No questions about citations are on-topic here. You could visit [academia.se] or [writers.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we're in the footnote already.  Now here comes the translation along with your little note:

> "bla bla in a surprisingly symbiotic relationship" **[translation my own]**.

That isn't the only way to do it but that is a common enough, simple way.

**Edit**: example: [Translation and Relevance](https://books.google.com/books?id=4ckJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=%22translation%20my%20own%22&source=bl&ots=PLawQisUDl&sig=6ZDCEUNGH7lYLHKnpqWABDttQ-M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb77maxPrSAhWD2YMKHW80AFsQ6AEIITAB): Cognition and Context
By Ernst-August Gutt

Comment: Thank you. So, are you suggesting "bla bla" (author date, page) [translation my own]? Do you think that this would be acceptable in academic writing?

Comment: @JohnPap - Yes, I have seen it this way and I have done it this way.  I've added a tiny bit of documentation to my answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!